# How to solve HTTP Status 500 - ContainerException java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Error

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, tomcat8

How to solve HTTP Status 500 -

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map
>   exception?

I am not able to understand the problem.
I am using Tomcat 8.

```
 <properties>
     <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>...
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwBy0.jpg)

[Hibernate class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zek8u.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError%3A+org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties%28%29

Comment: `dependencyManagement` is not well-formed XML. Some `version` attributes are also missing.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Try to look for an embedded hibernate library in your servlet container somewhere in the lib directory. It may contain some older version and it conflict with the one specified in the `pom.xml`

**2)** You are using the latest version of hibernate which builds on top of JPA 2.x. You are using version `1.0.2` which might be causing some clashes. Try to add a dependency to the newest `2.1` API and remove the existing one. For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```